# Transfering OWL data from client to server using GWT

Tags: gwt, jena, owl

I am working on a web application which is being developed using GWT. I am also using OWL ontologies and Jena framework to structure semantic contents in the application.

A simple function in the application would be getting some data from the user and send it to the servers side to be stored as a data graph using the ontology. I suppose one way would be to store the data as java class objects equivalent to the ontology classes and send them using the GWT async communication. To convert OWL classes to java, I used Jastor.

My question is that after the server receives the java class, is it possible to easily convert is to an OWL individual and add it to the data graph, using the functions of Jena and/or Jastor? For instance in the server side interface implementation we call something like this:

```
Public void StoreUser (User userObj) {
  //User: a Jastor created java class. userObj is instantiated using the user data on the client side.

  OntModel ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);
  //Open the ontology here using inputstream and ontModel.read!

  Individual indiv = (Individual) userObj.resource();

  //Add the individual to the model here! }
```

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any Jena function that can add an existing individual to the model.

Would you suggest another way to pass the ontology data to server side and store it, rather than using Jastor created classes (for instance using an XML file)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to the answer. First, an `Individual` is a sub-class of a Jena `Resource`, which is definitely something that you can add to a model. However, individual resources, or properties or literals are not stored in a `Model`. A `Model` stores only triples, represented as `Statement` objects in the Java API. So to add some resource to a model, you have to include it in a triple.

In Jena, an individual is defined as a subject of a triple whose predicate is `rdf:type` and whose object is not one of the built-in language classes. So if you have:

```
ex:my_car rdf:type ex:Ferrari .
ex:Ferrari rdf:type owl:Class .
```

(note: this example is entirely fictitious!), then `ex:my_car` would be an individual, but `ex:Ferrari` would not (because OWL `Class` is a built-in type). So, to add your individual to your model, you just need to assert that it is of some type. Since I don't know GWT and don't use Jastor, I can't say whether the type association that is normally part of a Jena `Individual` is retained after serialization. I suspect not, in which case you'll need to have some other means of determining the type of the individual you want to add, or use a different predicate than `rdf:type` to add the resource to the the `Model`.

All that said, personally I probably wouldn't solve your problem this way at all. Typically, when I'm working with client-side representations of server-side RDF, I send just the minimal information (e.g. URI and label) to the client as JSON. If I need any more data on a given resource, I either send it along with the initial JSON serialization, or it's just an Ajax call away. But, as I say, I don't use GWT so that advice may not be of any use to you.

Comment: Thank you very much dear Ian, I will be trying to find a way around my problem based on your very helpful answer. Thanks again!